# my old sd card crashed and when i replaced it, my device wouldn't allow me to take pictures, it says no external storage, how do i fix that?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

My device froze up and then automatically powered off. When I powered my device back on it said that there's was no sd card, and all of my pictures and videos were gone. When my sd card crashed, it deleted all of my pictures and videos. there's nothing in my gallery and I can't take pictures and videos anymore.

How do I not only fix the no external storage problem, but also get my media back?

Comment: To offer useful advice, we need to know exactly what happened. Don't say "it crashed", tell us what you saw.

Comment: For recovering data from your "crashed" sdcard, please take a look at our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info). As for the new one not working correctly: there are sometimes issues that combinations of device and card manufacturers don't work well together. You can try a different card from a different manufacturer, which in those cases was solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is easily disassembled, you might want to try powering off your phone, removing the SD card, replacing the SD card, and powering your phone on again. Sometimes the simplest things can fix tough problems for you.

If your phone still doesn't recognize the card, you might want to try plugging your SD card into your PC using a converter or card reader (MicroSD cards are usually sold with one that converts your MicroSD to a standard SD). Run a software like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) (or any other data recovery tool), and see if you can recover files from your card. If you can, download them to your computer. Then format your card to `FAT32`, reload the files onto your card, and plug it back into your phone. Best of luck to you.